# Aligning columns with respect to plus/minus and X symbol

Tags: symbols, align, columns

[image]I would like the data in the columns to be centered/aligned with respect to plus/minus and X symbols. Here is the code, I have used. Can someone please help me with it.

```
\begin{table}[b!]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize 
\caption{\label{tab:table1}
Summary of fiber characteristics. } 
\begin{tabular} {|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Type &  $\overline L [\mu$m] & $\overline D [\mu$m] & $\beta$  & $\overline L^+$ & $\tau$ [ms] & St & $ V_s$ [m/s]\\
\hline \hline
t1 & 921 $\pm$ 142 & 28 $\pm$ 2.1 & 32.9 $\pm$ 5.6 & 16 $\pm$ 2.5 & 0.21 $\pm$ 0.03 & 0.06 $\pm$ 0.01 & $-3 \times 10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t2 & 950 $\pm$ 96 & 15.3 $\pm$ 0.9  & 62.1 $\pm$ 7.3 & 16.5  $\pm$ 1.7 & 0.07 $\pm$ 0.009 & 0.02 $\pm$ 0.003 &  $-1 \times 10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t3 & 1446 $\pm$ 212 & 21.2 $\pm$ 0.97  & 68.2 $\pm$ 10.5 & 25.2  $\pm$ 3.7 & 0.14 $\pm$ 0.014 & 0.04 $\pm$ 0.004 &  $-2 \times 10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t4  & 1594 $\pm$ 174 & 52 $\pm$ 3.62 & 30.7 $\pm$ 3.9 & 27.7 $\pm$ 3& 0.7 $\pm$ 0.1 & 0.22 $\pm$ 0.03 & $-1.1 \times 10^{-3}$\\
\hline
t5  & 2917 $\pm$ 242 & 62 $\pm$ 5.5  & 47.0 $\pm$ 5.7 & 50.8  $\pm$ 4.2& 1.12 $\pm$ 0.2 & 0.34 $\pm$ 0.06 &  $-1.7 \times 10^{-3}$\\
\hline
t6 & 3044 $\pm$ 317 & 35.5 $\pm$ 6.5  & 85.5 $\pm$ 8.9 & 52.9  $\pm$ 5.5 & 0.41 $\pm$ 0.15 & 0.13 $\pm$ 0.05 &  $-6 \times 10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t7 & 3840 $\pm$ 414.6 & 38.5 $\pm$ 2.9  & 99.7 $\pm$ 10.7 & 66.8  $\pm$ 7.2 & 0.6 $\pm$ 0.09 & 0.18 $\pm$ 0.03 &  $-1.8 \times 10^{-3}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b!]
    \caption{Summary of fiber characteristics. }
\centering
\footnotesize
\sisetup{uncertainty-mode=separate}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}  
    \label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular} {|c||S[table-format=4.0(2)]
               *{3}{|S[table-format=2.1(3)]}
               *{2}{|S[table-format=1.3(4)]}
                    |S[table-format=-1.1e3,
                       round-mode=places,
                       round-precision=1]|}
\hline
Type    & {$\overline L [\mu$m]}    & {$\overline{D} [\mu$m]}   & {$\beta$}  
        & {$\overline L^+$ }        & {$\tau$ [ms]}             & {St}
        & {$V_s$ [m/s]  }       \\
\hline \hline
t1 & 921(142)   & 28.(21)   & 32.9(56)  & 16.(25)    & 0.21(3)   & 0.06(1)  & -3e-4 \\
\hline
t2 & 950(96)    & 15.3(9)   & 62.1(73)  & 16.5(17)  & 0.07(0.9) & 0.02(0.3) & -1e-4 \\
\hline
t3 & 1446(212)  & 21.2(97)  & 68.2(105) & 25.2(37)  & 0.14(1.4) & 0.04(0.4) & -2e-4 \\
\hline
t4 & 1594(174)  & 52.(362)  & 30.7(39)  & 27.7(3)   & 0.70(10)  & 0.22(3)  & -1.1e-3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
It seems that you prefer to have only aligned data at `\pm` sign. and consistency of data, which is required at use of `siunitx` package, is not important, than try the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{\label{tab:table1}
Summary of fiber characteristics. }
\begin{tabular} {|l|*{6}{r@{\,}c@{\,}l|} c | }
\hline
Type &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\overline L [\mu$m]} 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\overline D [\mu$m]} 
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\beta$}
                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\overline L^+$} 
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\tau$ [ms]} 
                        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{St} 
                            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$V_s$ [m/s]}\\
\hline \hline
t1 & 921 & $\pm$ & 142 & 28 & $\pm$ & 2.1 & 32.9 & $\pm$ & 5.6 & 16 & $\pm$ & 2.5 & 0.21 & $\pm$ & 0.03 & 0.06 & $\pm$ & 0.01 & $-3$ &$\times$&  $10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t2 & 950 & $\pm$ & 96 & 15.3 & $\pm$ & 0.9  & 62.1 & $\pm$ & 7.3 & 16.5 & $\pm$ & 1.7 & 0.07 & $\pm$ & 0.009 & 0.02 & $\pm$ & 0.003 &  $-1$ &$\times$& $10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t3 & 1446 & $\pm$ & 212 & 21.2 & $\pm$ & 0.97  & 68.2 & $\pm$ & 10.5 & 25.2 & $\pm$ & 3.7 & 0.14 & $\pm$ & 0.014 & 0.04 & $\pm$ & 0.004 &  $-2$ &$\times$& $10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t4  & 1594 & $\pm$ & 174 & 52 & $\pm$ & 3.62 & 30.7 & $\pm$ & 3.9 & 27.7 & $\pm$ & 3& 0.7 & $\pm$ & 0.1 & 0.22 & $\pm$ & 0.03 & $-1.1$ &$\times$& $10^{-3}$\\
\hline
t5  & 2917 & $\pm$ & 242 & 62 & $\pm$ & 5.5  & 47.0 & $\pm$ & 5.7 & 50.8 & $\pm$ & 4.2& 1.12 & $\pm$ & 0.2 & 0.34 & $\pm$ & 0.06 &  $-1.7$ &$\times$& $10^{-3}$\\
\hline
t6 & 3044 & $\pm$ & 317 & 35.5 & $\pm$ & 6.5  & 85.5 & $\pm$ & 8.9 & 52.9 & $\pm$ & 5.5 & 0.41 & $\pm$ & 0.15 & 0.13 & $\pm$ & 0.05 &  $-6$ &$\times$& $10^{-4}$\\
\hline
t7 & 3840 & $\pm$ & 414.6 & 38.5 & $\pm$ & 2.9 & 99.7 & $\pm$ & 10.7 & 66.8 & $\pm$ &7.2 & 0.6 & $\pm$ & 0.09 & 0.18 & $\pm$ & 0.03 &  $-1.8$ &$\times$& $10^{-3}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. The decimals after the plus/minus sign in columns #6 and #7 are not correct. How can I fix this? Also, I tried the same script and added the missing rows, it ends up with the same decimal places error in the result.

Comment: @Subhani, huh, this are errors at transcribing of uncertainties of `siunitx` format. Corrected now but please check, if it is now correct.

Comment: Hi. I got the following error and the field is blank after compiling.Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '0.14(1.4)'.

Comment: @Subhani, at me compilation is performed without any errors. Which version of `siunitx` you use? I test with v3.0.32, last revised 2021-09-29.

Comment: thanks. I am using the same version of the package. If possible could you please share the snapshot of the result? I see that, the decimals units are not correct in the posted picture.

Comment: @Subhani, sorry, I didn't load last version of table image. Now is corrected. I also a bit improve column formating.

Comment: @Subhani, decimal points are on correct place. Your data in table are not consistent, so consequently result is as you can see.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to rectify it.

Comment: @Subhani, see addendum to my answer. If answer solve your problem, you my consider to accept it :-)

Comment: Hi, awesome :). How can I do it for the last column and align with X symbol?

Comment: @Subhani, just insert one column more. See corrected addendum.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. I have replaced \begin{tabular} {|l|*{6}{r@{\,}c@{\,}l|} c | } with \begin{tabular} {|l|*{7}{r@{\,}c@{\,}l|} c | }. It did it job with the alignment but unfortunately, after compiling the extreme right vertical line bounding the table is missing. Could you please help me where am I wrong, this will solve this query. I have tried to fix it but did not succeed.